# Can I consolidate several BigQuery columns into a single repeated field via a single query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large table in BigQuery that looks like this:

```
ref_id code1 code2 code3 code4 code5 code6 code7 code8
     1    47   742    89   374   893    27     4    68
     2   766     9    84     8  4576    49    76     4
```

I would like to transform this table, using a BigQuery query, into a format that uses a repeated field for all the code columns. So the result would look like this (represented with JSON to demonstrate the repeated field for the codes):

```js
[{
  "ref_id": 1,
  "codes": [
    46,
    742,
    89,
    374,
    893,
    27,
    4,
    68
  ]
}, {
  "ref_id": 2,
  "codes": [
    766,
    9,
    84,
    8,
    4576,
    49,
    76,
    4
  ]
}]
```

Can I do that via a BigQuery query that outputs to another table? I know I could download the data, reformat it into JSON and then re-insert, but with several billion rows I was hoping I could do it via a query on the original data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach - concatenate the codes with "," as separator, and then use SPLIT to produce REPEATED field, i.e.

```
select id, split(concat(string(code1), ",", string(code2))) codes from
(select 1 id, 47 code1, 742 code2),
(select 2 id, 766 code1, 9 code2)
```

Comment: No,  nest can only take one field